# How to convert "\x81" to "ü" with codepage 1252 (windows 1252)

Tags: python, codepages, windows-1252, cp1252

I am stuck with a simple task. I want to convert

```
\x81
```

into

```
ü
```

with the use of codepage 1252 (windows 1252).

My attempt:

```
data = "\x81"
print(data.encode('cp1252'))
```

results with an error:

```
      File "test.py", line 2, in <module>
    print(data.encode('cp1252'))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/encodings/cp1252.py", line 12, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,errors,encoding_table)
    UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\x81' in position 0: character maps to <undefined>
```

Can someone help?

Comment: I receive \x81 from my serial port. So it looks like I receive cp437 there. How can I convert it to \xFC for cp1252?

Comment: How do you read it from the serial port? Usually you should get bytes and .`decode()` them with the right encoding.

Comment: I read with ser.read(int(bytesInBuffer)). I get the datatype 'bytes'. 
I get \x81 for the ü character when I print what I just read from the serial port.
I get 81 when I convert it to hex.

Comment: You should update your questions. Having bytes makes a large difference.

Comment: '\x81' does not exist in the CP1252 codepage. ü is '\xFC'

Comment: Having a bytes object: `b"\x81".decode('cp437')` returns string `'ü'`… And `b"\x81".decode('cp437').encode('cp1252')` --> `b'\xfc'`